# Binding Combobox with Dictionary object, but setting selected value in code behind not taking effect

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, binding, selectedvalue

Here is my `ComboBox` instantiated in the XAML

```
<Combobox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Delimiters}" DisplayMemberPath="Key"
          SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedDelimiter, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Here is the corresponding bindings in the view model with the `Dictionary` populated in the constructor:

```
private IDictionary<string,string> _delimiters;

public IDictionary<string,string> Delimiters
{
   get{return _delimiters;}
   set{_delimiters = value;  RaisePropertyChanged("Delimiters");}
}

private KeyValuePair <string, string> _selectedDelimiter;
public KeyValuePair <string, string> SelectedDelimiter
{
    get{return _selectedDelimiter;}
    set{
       if(value.Key != _selectedDelimiter.Key || value.Value != _selectedDelimiter.Value)
       {
           var prevDelimiter = _selectedDelimiter;
           _selectedDelimiter = value;
           if(IllegalDelimiter.Contains(_selectedDelimiter)
           {
                 MessageBox.Show("errror", "error");
                 _selectedDelmiter = prevDelimiter;
           }
           RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedDelimiter");
       }

    }
}
```

I am having trouble with binding the selected value back. The `Dictionary` is getting bound and when I make a changed to the UI `ComboBox`, the setting is being fired correctly. In the if statement to check if its an illegal delimiter, it does set the selected value back to its original value in the code behind, but it doesn't populate to the `ComboBox` UI (I see the get accessor firing from the UI). Its like setting `SelectedValue` doesn't really do anything to the UI.

if someone could point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took a while to figure out, I was setting things correctly, but because I was updating the same property in the setter, I needed to use a dispatcher to create a new thread to do the update correctly.

Comment: i am facing something similar.. if you remember can you let me know what you meant by "updating the same property in the setter" ??

Answer (score 7):

You should set `SelectedValuePath` if you are going to use the `SelectedValue`, presumably to `Value`. `SelectedValue` is doing a "selection", so your property type should be different as well.

If you want to retain the whole `KeyValuePair` you should bind the `SelectedItem` instead.

Comment: I used to have the `SelectValuePath=Value` and my SelectedDelimiter as a char, but it would result in the same behavior when I attempted to change it..

I have also tried binding with the KvP to SelectedItem, with no change.

Comment: @Tim: Did you actually set the property in code? If you set the field the binding will never update as no notifications are being raised.